# Updating MySQL table with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using `node-mysql` to update a MySQL database table from node.js. I want to update the timestamp column of a row with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. However, no changes seem to be made by node.js using the following code:

**Node.js Code**

```
client.query('UPDATE listings SET job_checkout_timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE listing_id = 1515');
```

But works if I were to replace `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` with a javascript time function, like `new Date()`

```
client.query('UPDATE listings SET job_checkout_timestamp = ? WHERE listing_id = 1515', [ new Date() ]);
```

However, if I were to execute the same SQL query directly into mysql (using Navicat), the row gets updated with the current timestamp!

**Direct SQL Query**

```
UPDATE listings SET job_checkout_timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE listing_id = 1515;
```

Did something go wrong somewhere?

Comment: Can you try `select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`?

Comment: Yes, `select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` works both directly and through node.js

Comment: I wondering is it node.js convert all the value to string instead of mysql variable. So, you should replace it `now()`, which is the same as current_timestamp. Hopefully node.js won't do any changes to function call.

Comment: you will have the same problem if you try with "null" value. Check this out : https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/lib/client.js#L145

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that node.js might convert the input variables into string,
and make the current_timestamp as string rather than mysql variables,
by replace the current_timestamp to synonym function call like :-

```
now()
current_timestamp()
```

should fix the problem