# Variable in MySQL Query causes error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a node.js app using node-mysql to query a MySQL database.

**Problem:** It appears that when I make the table name in the query a variable, things stop working. Did I miss out on something?

**Working Node Code**

```
client.query('SELECT * from tableA',
                function(error, results, fields) {
                    if (error)
                        throw error;
                    callback(results);
                });
```

**Non-working Node Code**

```
client.query('SELECT * from ?',
                [ tableA ],
                function(error, results, fields) {
                    if (error)
                        throw error;
                    callback(results);
                });
```

Comment: Tablenames can't usually be passed as parameters. You need to use dynamic SQL instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [*use a variable for table name in mysql sproc*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754423/use-a-variable-for-table-name-in-mysql-sproc) and [*In MySQL: How to pass a table name as stored procedure and/or function argument?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977356/in-mysql-how-to-pass-a-table-name-as-stored-procedure-and-or-function-argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably just append the table name to the string (pseudo code, I don't know node.js)

```
client.query('SELECT * from ' + [tablaA],
                function(error, results, fields) {
                    if (error)
                        throw error;
                    callback(results);
                });
```

Comment: and you kinda have the answer in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317472/inserting-variables-into-sql-query-for-node-mysql :)

Comment: Right, I was wondering if this applies to MySQL queries in general like in PHP, or is this node.js specific

Comment: In Mysql table names are not allowed to be variables (?) in prepared statements and I guess that nodejs is doing a prepared statement in the background.

Answer (score 0):

They reason why it's not working is pretty clear.

The query from the non-working code will be :

> SELECT * from 'tableA'

A solution is the one from @Andreas, but you will have the same problem in a where statement or insert for other values you don't want to be escaped like "null" value. ( convert into a string)

Same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288183/updating-mysql-table-with-current-timestamp-in-node-js)

Check out the [source](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/lib/client.js#L145) how format && escape from node-mysql works.

Comment: Am i right to say that table names, database names, column names cannot be escaped, while values to be added to the columns and MySQL functions can?

Comment: I would say yes, placeholders are normally for dynamic data (parameters)